# Jenkinsfile compare two env

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to compare two env and run iff condition based on result. I tried following

```
            steps {

                script {
                    if (${BUILD_NUMBER}.toInteger() != ${DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER}.toInteger()) {
                        echo "DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER not equal to BUILD_NUMBER."
                        sh "exit 1"
                    }
                }
             .....
             }
```

But failed with following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps
```

Whats is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: Not tested in real.]

See [Groovy Syntax, 4.4.1. String interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation):

> Here, we have a string with a placeholder referencing a local variable:
>
> ```groovy
> def name = 'Guillaume' // a plain string
> def greeting = "Hello ${name}"
>
> assert greeting.toString() == 'Hello Guillaume'
> ```

So, given that [`groovy.lang.GString`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html#method.summary):

> Double-quoted strings are plain `java.lang.String` if there’s no interpolated expression, but are `groovy.lang.GString` instances if interpolation is present.

supports `toInteger()` this should work for you:

```groovy
...
if ("${BUILD_NUMBER}".toInteger() != "${DEPLOY_BUILD_NUMBER}".toInteger()) {
...
```

but apparently it doesn't, so simply compare the strings (and possibly trim them before).

P.S.: Just out of curiosity: Where did you get that `<local variable>.toInteger()` from?